# Open modal window with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a working modal which has the following code:

```
<!-- modal code -->
<a href="#follow" rel="modal:open"> Follow </a>
<!-- modal window  -->
<div id="ex1" style="display:none">
    <p> Please <%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %> </a> to Extend. </p>
</div>
```

I made a div class named "extend-button". I want to show the modal by clicking on that div.

```
<li class="extend-button"> Extend  </li>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".extend-button").mouseup(function(){
        $("#ex1").dialog('open');  
    });
});
```

This isn't working.

Comment: I solved it by changing html code.
 <a href="#ex1" rel="modal:open" class="extend-button"> Extend </a>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using the `click()` function. Otherwise all appears well, assuming `dialog('open')` works as intended. Add a console log to ensure the click event handler is working to help you debug.

```
$('.extend-button').click(function (e) { 
   console.log('clicked');
   $("#ex1").dialog('open'); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did it a bit differently.
    <a href="#ex1" rel="modal:open" class="extend-button"> Extend </a>

Comment: Great, either works! If you have no other questions please consider marking this question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first move all your jquery codes into the `<script>` tag. Then replace `$(".extend-button").mouseup` with `$(".extend-button").click`.

The difference between a `mouseup` event and a `click` event is that, with a `mouseup` event, you can click your mouse, hold it, and drag the mouse pointer any and everywhere before releasing the mouse to trigger a `mouseup` event. A click event requires the `mousedown` and `mouseup` event to happen on the **same** element.

The normal expectation is that a click requires both the `mousedown` and `mouseup` event.

Answer (score 0):

The following change in HTML made my day. No jquery was needed.

```
     <a href="#ex1" rel="modal:open" class="extend-button"> Extend </a>
```

Comment: I think it's still important for you to replace `mouseup` with `click`. They imply different things, and might cause you some headache later. Take a look at my answer for their difference.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you are including the JQuery UI library and CSS file in the `<head>` of your page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

HTML:

```
<!-- modal code -->
<a href="#follow" rel="modal:open"> Follow </a>
<!-- modal window  -->
<div id="ex1" style="display:none">
    <p> Please <%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %> </a> to Extend. </p>
</div>

<li class="extend-button"> Extend  </li>
```

You also need to make sure you are wrapping the code in `<script>` tags. As @elzi mentioned may be better to use a `.click()` event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(".extend-button").on("click", function(){
        $("#ex1").dialog('open');  
    });
});
</script>
```